# How to solve a linear system with 3 equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

Can someone help me to solve this linear system?

The question is :
Determine $a$ such that the equation system below has unique solution. Also determine the solution for such $a$.

```
2x + y - az  = 3
3x + 4y +2az = 1
 x -  y + z  = 2
```

I have tried many times to find a way to solve it but I did not succeed?

Comment: I suspect $a$ is *not* a variable, but a constant.

Comment: It's not possible to find the constant $a$, unless you allow yourself to solve as an expression in terms of the variables. Perhaps you are misreading the question and want an $a$ such that this system is *underdetermined*?

Comment: Can you tell us how you have been trying to solve this, so that we might better help you?

Comment: I have posted the question. I have tried to solve it by the elimination but I could not get the right answer

Comment: Are you familiar with determinants? You should write this system in matrix form, and compute the determinant of the $3 \times 3$ matrix associated to it.

Comment: but what should I write for a and z ? ( 2*1*1= 2 ) should i write just 2 instead for them ?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: A system has a unique solution if the determinant is non-zero.

$$\begin{vmatrix} 2 & 1 & -a \\ 3 & 4 & 2a \\ 1 & -1 & 1\end{vmatrix} \neq 0$$

Expand along the last column

$$-7(-a)-2a(-3)+5 \neq 0$$

I believe you can handle the rest?